# Minimal wallet application for a cold storage

Tags: cold-storage

I wonder if there are some convenient set of tools (or a wallet application itself) to work on a cold storage.

As I can understand (correct me if I'm wrong) to work with a cold storage I only need to have abilities to:

- generate a private key of a new wallet
- get the public key and the address of the wallet from the private key
- sign transactions generated by other apps (watch-only wallets) with the private key

**Is there are some apps that support all the basic tools that one need on a cold storage computer to work with an Ethereum wallet?**

OS: Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com) is highly respected. There's a link in the footer to https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/latest, which lets you download the site to run fully offline. You just need a web browser. It can generate new keys and sign transactions offline.

If you prefer a command-line tool, `geth` is a pretty good option. It can also do all the things you need.

Comment: Thanks, I will check both. Seems like geth the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed new OWNR wallet got a page for developers, yes it is not really ethereum wallet but they have all of ERC-20 tokens